# Opening multiple html files in PhantomJs via PHP throws syntax error

Tags: php, html, apache, syntax-error, phantomjs

I want my php script to call phantomjs from command line, which will generate muliple pdf's out of many html files. So I have a concatenated string with paths to my html files, and next I invoke `exec` command :

```
$myFile1 = dirname(__FILE__)."/testFile0.html";
$myFile2 = dirname(__FILE__)."/testFile1.html";
$myFile3 = dirname(__FILE__)."/testFile2.html";

$files = array($myFile1, $myFile2, $myFile3);

$command = 'phantomjs '.dirname(__FILE__).'/render.js '.implode('|', $files);
exec($command, $phantomOut);

echo print_r($phantomOut);
```

When I'm calling 'phantomjs render.js "file1.html|file2.html"' everything works fine. But, when trying to do this from the php script I'm getting the following error in apache error_log:

```
testFile1.html: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `<'  
testFile1.html: line 1: `<!DOCTYPE HTML...
```

The HTML files I'm using look fine, so I'm out of ideas on what can cause this. The output when running this script in the browser is : `Array ( ) 1` instead of the text I'm getting in the command line.

Below is the PhantomJs rendering script :

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    addresses = phantom.args[0],
    outputPath = '/path_to_pdf/',
    outputFilename,
    filesArray, outputArray = [],
    loadInProgress = false,
    pageIndex = 0, 
    interval;

page.viewportSize = { width: 600, height: 600};

if(addresses.indexOf('|') !== -1){
    filesArray = addresses.split('|');
} else{
    filesArray = [addresses];
}

interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (!loadInProgress && pageIndex < filesArray.length) {
        page.open(filesArray[pageIndex]);
    }
    if (pageIndex === filesArray.length) {
        console.log('OUTPUT: ', outputArray.join('|'));
        phantom.exit();
    }
}, 250);

page.onLoadStarted = function() {
    loadInProgress = true;
};

page.onLoadFinished = function() {
    loadInProgress = false;
    outputFilename = 'print'+pageIndex+'.pdf';
    page.render(outputPath+outputFilename);
    outputArray.push(outputFilename);
    pageIndex++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried wrapping paths to those files that you get after implode inside a quotation ? It looks like an invalid parameter to me, although the error itself is strange.

Comment: hmm indeed when calling in the console I've added them, I'll check if it solves the problem. But how would the error in the error_log be relevant in this case ?

Comment: @mike_hornbeck  Which part of the code did you change to fix ?

Comment: What I meant is that `implode('|', $files)` will just list files in the console as single parameters `<textfromfile> <textfromfile>`, when in fact they should be wrapped in `"` like `"<textfromfile>"`